# How to fix [File of type 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth'] this?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, botframework

i have tried using the bot builder samples authentication code but I am getting this error [File of type 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth']
I'm thinking that it may have a fault with a hero card

```
       const reply = { attachments: [], attachmentLayout: AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel };
        for (let cnt = 0; cnt < numberOfMessages; cnt++) {
            const mail = messages[cnt];
            const card = CardFactory.heroCard(
                mail.subject,
                mail.bodyPreview,
                [{ alt: 'Outlook Logo', url: 'https://botframeworksamples.blob.core.windows.net/samples/OutlookLogo.jpg' }],
                [],
                { subtitle: `${ mail.from.emailAddress.name } <${ mail.from.emailAddress.address }>` }
            );
            reply.attachments.push(card);
        }
        await context.sendActivity(reply);
    } else {
        await context.sendActivity('Unable to find any recent unread mail.');
    }
}
```

I should get the hero card with the sign-in button but I am not getting that one

Comment: Seems to be a known issue that is documented in [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4632#issuecomment-441957719) GitHub issue, the comment in the issue outlines a potential solution.

Comment: but most of the links present in the explanation are not available now .. tq

Comment: The comment that I linked to has a solution that you can try.

Comment: Are you getting the error on the emulator or on the azure portal? Also, are you using  an iframe to embed webchat or implementing a webchat on your own?

Comment: i tried in both webchat and local emulator where its showing  [File of type 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth'] and oops something went wrong respectively.

Comment: we tried to edit iframe to encode the directline secret but it cannot be edited..

Comment: You will need to update your emulator and test it again. The OAuth cards works just fine on the emulator. For web chat, in the Azure portal the webchat tab is using an older version of webchat that will not render the cards, the same is true if you are using the iFrame version of webchat.

Comment: Thank you, @ranusharao and matt stannett for the valuable inputs.. now i am able the get the cards but it working in other channels but in teams im not able to bring the access token and can u pls, help me with this.

Comment: There are currently some [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-oauth-card#support-for-the-oauthcard) as to where you can use OAuth cards in Teams. Also, you can have a look at https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1236 on GitHub which has a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth cards render just fine on the emulator. If it doesn't, then you need to update the emulator and try testing again. For web chat, in the Azure portal the webchat tab is using an older version of webchat that will not render the cards, the same is true if you are using the iFrame version of webchat.